# Is there a command to use global send keys to Zoom in on a Browser Window in Chrome with Blue Prism

Tags: google-chrome-extension, blueprism

I am having difficulty with using the correct Global Send Keys to Zoom in on a browser window with Blue Prism. I need to send "CTRL" "Z" key and "+".

I currently have "^Z+"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct Global Send Keys to Zoom in on a browser window is `^(Z{ADD})`

Comment: Thank you for that. That worked perfectly.

Comment: What is the Global Send Keys to Zoom Out on a browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Cheers Gary, you might want to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=net-5.0 for a more comprehensive list of the available codes for the Send Key statement.

^(z{ADD}) zooms in while ^(z{SUBSTRACT}) zooms out the browser ;)